# How Send emails in queue in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I tried to send email in a queue, but not working.

```php
Mail::queue('emails.mailsubscribe', ['email'=>$email], 
    function($message) use($email)
    {
       $message->to('user@xxx.in')->subject('Subscribe: XXXXX');
    });
```

Comment: Did you start the queue by `php artisan queue:work` command?

Comment: No, I haven't run that command

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to make `Laravel 5/6` full queuing you need make below steps:

1. `php artisan queue:table` (for jobs)
2. `php artisan queue:failed-table` (for failed jobs)
3. `php artisan migrate`
4. Set in .env `QUEUE_DRIVER=database`
5. Fire: `php artisan config:cache`
6. Fire queuing: `php artisan queue:work database --tries=1` (after all uncompleted tries it will be registered in failed jobs table)

Since sending email messages can drastically lengthen the response time of your application, many developers choose to queue email messages for background sending. Laravel makes this easy using its built-in unified queue API. To queue a mail message, use the queue method on the Mail facade after specifying the message's recipients:

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->queue(new OrderShipped($order));
```

This method will automatically take care of pushing a job onto the queue so the message is sent in the background. Of course, you will need to configure your queues before using this feature.

If you wish to delay the delivery of a queued email message, you may use the later method. As its first argument, the later method accepts a DateTime instance indicating when the message should be sent:

```
$when = now()->addMinutes(10);

Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->later($when, new OrderShipped($order));
```

If you have mailable classes that you want to always be queued, you may implement the  ShouldQueue contract on the class. Now, even if you call the send method when mailing, the mailable will still be queued since it implements the contract:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderShipped extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Copied word by word from Laravel Doc? What;s so great about it? At least the source should be indicated if you copy/paste? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail

Comment: i know it's a copy  paste, but it's really neat to just show the summary

Comment: Not sure which version this changed, but in L6, it is now `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` as opposed to `QUEUE_DRIVER`. I initially used the QUEUE_DRIVER property in your post and then ran the config:cache command to find it didn't work, and when I realised the new .env property name and changed it to QUEUE_CONNECTION, I hadn't thought to reset the config cache again which caused a few frustrating hours of mail just getting sent without hitting the queue

Comment: Yes in Laravel versions 6 and above you can specify your driver type in the QUEUE_CONNECTION.

Comment: If default Redis client not working use REDIS_CLIENT=predis

Comment: This solution is so much better than all others, which suggest creating a separate Job to handle the email sending. Thank you kind stranger!